# HOW-TO Create an Array of Hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, push

New to ruby and I'm trying to create an array of hashes (or do I have it backwards?)

```
def collection
  hash = { "firstname" => "Mark", "lastname" => "Martin", "age" => "24", "gender" => "M" }
  array = []
  array.push(hash)
  @collection = array[0][:firstname]
end
```

@collection does not show the firstname for the object in position 0... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You're using a `Symbol` as the index into the `Hash` object that uses `String` objects as keys, so simply do this:

```
@collection = array[0]["firstname"]
```

I would encourage you to use `Symbol`s as `Hash` keys rather than `String`s because `Symbol`s are cached, and therefore more efficient, so this would be a better solution:

```
def collection
  hash = { :firstname => "Mark", :lastname => "Martin", :age => 24, :gender => "M" }
  array = []
  array.push(hash)
  @collection = array[0][:firstname]
end
```

Comment: Sorry.. I dont understand.. so what should @collection be?

Answer (score 3):

You have defined the keys of your hash as `String`. But then you are trying to reference it as `Symbol`. That won't work that way.

Try

```
@collection = array[0]["firstname"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
@collection = [{ "firstname" => "Mark", "lastname" => "Martin", "age" => "24", "gender" => "M" }]
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem of the OP. Nor do I understand what problem you try to solve with the code you propose. Since this question still attracts visitors this answer can still confuse visitors. I would suggest to remove it.

Comment: @PaulvanLeeuwen I think you right, this answer more response to title of question, when question itself ask quite another thing. If we remove array from context of question at all, there will be still problem with access to hash element by key. So I would recommend renaming the question title to "How to access to Hash element properly in Ruby". Therefore I thought that some people came here exactly for "Create an Array of Hashes in Ruby" and for them it will be useful. So If didn't convince you I will immediately delete it ))